# music21 --> simplifyMultipleEnharmonics not available?

Tags: python, attributeerror, music21

I'm trying to use the function pitch.simplifyMultipleEnharmonics(...): http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/modulePitch.html#functions

but at line:

```
print music21.pitch.simplifyEnharmonics([pitch.Pitch('G3'),
                                         pitch.Pitch('C-4'),
                                         pitch.Pitch('D4')])
```

I get the error:

```
>>> 'module' object has no attribute 'simplifyMultipleEnharmonics'
```

... I'm using the latest version of music21 (just pip installed again).

... Is this function available only in an older version of music21?

Thanks very much for any help!

Comment: a text search for "simplifyMultipleEnharmonics" in pitch.py returns nothing -- it's just not in there. but the function is in the docs ... http://web.mit.edu/music21/doc/moduleReference/modulePitch.html#functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a new function for v3 which is the GitHub master branch so it's not in any of the releases yet. Sorry. Versioned docs are on the priority list to prevent problems like this.

Comment: Ok no problem, thanks for the quick answer! Is there a way I can use a workaround to recognize chords that have problems with enharmonics (with music21.harmony.chordSymbolFigureFromChord(thisChord))? or otherwise would it be possible to get a link to the repo so I can try to experimentally paste in simplifyMultipleEnharmonics?

Comment: Ok, now when calling: 
simplifyMultipleEnharmonics(['F#2', 'E4', 'B-3'], criterion='maximizeConsonance', keyContext=None)
I get:
F#2
... is this expected behaviour? 
Thanks so much Michael, and great work btw for music21!!!

Comment: Since these are development questions, they're probably better discussed on the github repo or on the Google Groups music21 list -- discussing changes to the source code is really hard to do on stack overflow.